# Error Handling in DWR

Tags: java, ajax, dwr

I am working on a Java web-application which uses DWR in a number of places. I am adding a new DWR component, which must not propogate any errors back to the end-user. Currently, if there's a server-side error, this is displayed in a pop-up to the user, which I want to prevent. So there are two parts to this:

1) according http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/browser/errors.html, errors-handling is configured via the:

`dwr.engine.setErrorHandler(handler);`

call, but I can't find this in our code-base. Does this mean the existing popup is just the DWR default behaviour?

2) If I supress the existing message with a call to

```
dwr.engine.setErrorHandler(handler);
```

where handler does nothing, does this just affect the only the pages where I make this call, or will I have wiped out the default-handler for other pages (which I want to keep)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, I've overriden this and it works correctly so

1. it does seem to be DWR default behaviour
2. setting the handler only changes the behaviour for the current page